# Why 504 gateway error is happening on Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

While I was trying to GET group's 1000 threads using Microsoft Graph API on PowerShell, 504 gateway error is happening and the code stopped.

But if I re-execute the code without any change, it ran well. Why this happens and how should I avoid this issue?

```
$apiUrl53 = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/" + $groups.id + "/threads?top=1000"
    $Data = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $global:__authHeader -Uri $apiUrl53 -Method Get
```

Error Message :

```
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850282/microsoft-graph-api-errors

Comment: what is the request-id returned with your response?

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT Can you guide me how to print from Powershell?

Comment: You can output the error message

try
{
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "www.microsoft.com/unkownhost" -ErrorAction Stop
    # This will only execute if the Invoke-WebRequest is successful.
    $StatusCode = $Response.StatusCode
}
catch
{
    $StatusCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
}
$StatusCode

404


See example 7 here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you are trying to get the top 1000?

You can 'page' through the groups in records of 100 for instance, so you aren't returning such a huge payload in one response.

There is a great video on this that shows how to use the skiptoken https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

For example, the following URL requests all the users in an organization with a page size of 5, specified with the $top query parameter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=100
```

If the result contains more than five users, Microsoft Graph will return an @odata:nextLink property similar to the following along with the first page of users.

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=100&$skiptoken=X%274453707 ... 6633B900000000000000000000%27"
```

You can retrieve the next page of results by sending the URL value of the @odata:nextLink property to Microsoft Graph.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=100&$skiptoken=X%274453707 ... 6633B900000000000000000000%27
```

Microsoft Graph will continue to return a reference to the next page of data in the @odata:nextLink property with each response until all pages of the result have been read.