# Microsoft Graph API Errors

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've been using Microsoft Graph Api's v1.0 [List messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) method 
for nearly five months.

In the last few days it started returning errors when ever i add the **$search** parameter in my query string. It gives either a **503** or **504** error code

The error is received after give or take 20 sec.

along with following message:

```
 {
      "error": {
      "code": "UnknownError",
       "message": "",
       "innerError": {
           "request-id": "8fd1d9ed-cde6-4237-b1a7-ab089a28d37e",
             "date": "2019-07-02T10:09:48"
       }
   }
}
```

[Microsoft Graph errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors)

```
  503   Service Unavailable The service is temporarily unavailable for maintenance or is overloaded. You may repeat the request after a delay, the length of which may be specified in a Retry-After header.

  504   Gateway Timeout The server, while acting as a proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server it needed to access in attempting to complete the request. May occur together with 503.
```

I am calling the api methods via microsoft's Developer tool 
[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

[image: Screen shot with Error and request]

Example of the API call that use to work until lately:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<COMPANY_ID>/users/<USER_ID>/messages?
$search=%22from:<MY_EMAIL>%22&$top=10
```

Example of an API call which always works (with out the $search parameter)

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<COMPANY_ID>/users/<USER_ID>/messages
```

> I was unable to get assistance from MS support in this matter.  They
>   actually refereed me to SO.

Hopefully someone came across this issue and can shed some light on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing this error consistently when you add $search.  I just tried it and it is working for me.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Almost always Yes. Playing around with it today, I found out that certain mailbox's with minimal search criteria do return. But even those mailbox's with just one more search criteria gives that same timeout error.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, which also just started a few days ago. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880644/why-do-i-get-gateway-timeout-on-no-result-queries-of-office-365-shared-mailbox-v). That makes 3 of us, so now I'm certain it's a new Graph bug or breaking change (or a bug/breaking change to the underlying Office365 API).

Answer (score 1):

I'm hitting a similar issue searching Emails through the Graph-API.

Digging into it, it's happening to my queries where there are no results to return. To test, I took the term I was searching for in one of the failed queries and sent a test mail with that term in the subject line of the email to the box I was searching. Next query returned a result immediately.

I then deleted the email, tried again, and received a 504 again.

**Update 7/5**: The issue appears to have been resolved for me, I no longer receive a 504 on null results

Comment: I get results when not searching for anything specific. The mailbox is there. But i'll look into it thanks.

Comment: You're not alone. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880644/why-do-i-get-gateway-timeout-on-no-result-queries-of-office-365-shared-mailbox-v). Have you had any luck troubleshooting this?